# Pyspark: How do I extract lowest values per key?

Tags: python, pyspark

My dataframe df:

```
C1    C2    C3
A     1     5
A     1     4
A     2     6
B     2     9
B     5     5
```

I would like to extract the lowest value from C2 per distinct value in C1 as a new dataframe. So the output would be

```
C1    C2
A     1
B     2
```

I think I'd have to use df.groupBy("C1"), but I'm not sure how to apply it correctly.

Comment: you need to add an aggregation after grouping `df.groupBy('C1').agg(F.min("C2").alias("C2")).show()` or  sort the values and drop duplicates `df.orderBy(*["C1","C2"]).dropDuplicates(['C1']).select("C1","C2").show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the correct function is df.groupBy("C1"). One can also apply the min function to that, simplifying the solution to one line of:

```
df.groupby(['C1']).min()
```

which will return the output. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

below is another way of doing it.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy(F.col("C1")).agg({"C2":"min"}).orderBy(F.col("C1")).show()
```